# Reload dynatable data

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dynatable

I'm using dynatable to power up my tables. It's how I'm using it:

```
function getData(obj) {
    $.getJSON("AjaxEngine/AddPayment.aspx", { sender: "seller-factor", id: 1 })
            .done(function (data) {

                var dynatable = $('#factors-table').dynatable({
                    dataset: {
                        records: data.Factors
                    },
                    features: {
                        paginate: false,
                        search: false,
                        recordCount: true,
                        perPageSelect: false
                    }

                })
                .bind('dynatable:afterProcess', bindSelectRow);
}
```

`getData()` will be fired on `change()` event of a `select`. When user select an Item for the first time it works fine, but when selected item changes it won't load new data. I asked in plugin's couple of days ago but got no answer.

I've tried multiple methods, like this one:

```
function getData(){        
            $.getJSON("AjaxEngine/AddPayment.aspx", { sender: "seller-factor", id: 1 },
            function (data) {                
                var dynatable = $('#factors-table').data('dynatable');                
                dynatable.records.updateFromJson({records: data});
                dynatable.records.init();               
                dynatable.process();                
            });  

        }
```

It says `dynatable.records` is **undefined** while when I log `dynatable` it's an object. 
I think as a trick it would be possible to check if `dynatable` is applied to the table and if it is, destroy it first then re-apply it, But I don't know how to do it.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/pDVvx/16/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, after couple of hours I managed it with this code:

```
$.getJSON("AjaxEngine/AddPayment.aspx", { 
    sender: "seller-factor", id: obj.val() }, 
    function (data) {
    var dynatable = $('#factors-table').dynatable({ 
    dataset: { records: data.Factors } }, 
    { features: { pushState: false }}).data("dynatable");
                        dynatable.settings.dataset.originalRecords =  data.Factors;
                        dynatable.process();  
});
```